# Pointer-like classes and the ->* operator

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-overloading, c++14, smart-pointers

I've recently come across the need to apply a pointer-to-member to the object  designated by an iterator. I've tried the natural syntax :

```
ite->*ptr = 42;
```

To my dismay, it didn't compile. Iterators don't overload `operator->*`, but more surprisingly neither do smart pointers. I needed to resort to the following clunkiness :

```
(*ite).*ptr = 42;
```

Experimenting (see the live example below) has shown that such a syntax seems to be achievable for custom classes, for both pointers-to-members and pointers-to-member-functions, at least since C++14.

Thus :

- Is there a reason the standard pointer-like classes don't overload `operator->*`, or is it just an oversight ?
- Should I overload `operator->*` when defining my own pointer-like classes, or does this same reason apply to me ?

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbb4b44c26ca5fdd) -- what compiles, what doesn't, and a proof-of-concept for a custom class.

Comment: @Galik I do mean pointers-to-members, not plain members. Have a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106975/error-in-using-unique-ptr-with-member-function-pointer some good points are made there

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696664/about-shared-ptr-and-pointer-to-member-operator-and-stdbind - although that's more about pointer to member functions rather than pointer to data members.

Comment: @Hcorg thank you very much, that was instructive -- member functions are indeed a pain. However they seem fine in C++14 (I updated the example).

Comment: @ecatmur it did bring up something **really** interesting that I didn't realize : it's possible to define `operator->*` as a non-member. Unless such an operator is a terrible idea, it could be "hot-patched" onto the standard classes. Neat, thank you !

Comment: @Quentin so maybe standard committee did not though  about it, when they made necessary changes in C++14 :) or they do not like pointer-to-members (AFAIK std::function and lambdas are preferred now)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can overload `->*` with a free function. It doesn't have to be a member.

```
template <typename P,
          typename T,
          typename M>
M& operator->* (P smartptr, M T::*ptrmem)
{
    return (*smartptr).*ptrmem;
}
```

Now everything that has unary `operator*` defined (iterators, smart pointers, whatever) can also use `->*`. You may want to do it in a bit more controlled fashion, i.e. define it for known iterators, known smart pointers etc. separately.

This will not work for member functions for obvious reasons. One would need to specialize/overload for this case and return a bound `std::function` instead:

```
template <typename P,
          typename T,
          typename M,
          typename ... Arg>
std::function<M(Arg&&...)> 
operator->* (P smartptr, M (T::*ptrmem)(Arg... args))
{
    return [smartptr,ptrmem](Arg&&... args) -> M 
      { return ((*smartptr).*ptrmem)(std::forward<Arg>(args)...); };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want to do `((&*ite)->*ptr) = 42;` ?

Comment: Sorry.
Is that it `((&*ite)->*ptr) = 42;` ?

Comment: This works, but is specifically the work-around I'd like not to have to use. Do notice that the question is not about a practical problem to be solved, but why it couldn't be solved with natural syntax, even though it is technically possible to achieve that syntax.

Comment: In fact there is a natural syntax `ite->*ptr = 42;` that's calling the member of the iterator class. If you overload the operator, you can't use it to call members of the iterator. That's why it isn't.

Comment: But an iterator is not a pointer, so without overloading `ite->*ptr` is incorrect, `ite.*ptr` is. Anyway, multiple overloads can distinguish between members belonging to the iterator, and members belonging to its pointee.

Comment: Also, I didn't notice that you don't have the required reputation to comment yet, sorry about that.