# Member function call on shared_ptr through member function pointer in template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, pointers, smart-pointers

This is a template function that takes a pointer (or a pointer like object) and a member function:

```
template <typename Ptr, typename MemberFunctor>
int example(Ptr ptr, MemberFunctor func )
{
    return (ptr->*func)();
}
```

If works when used with ordinary pointer:

```
struct C
{
    int getId() const { return 1; }
};

C* c = new C;
example(c, &C::getId);    // Works fine
```

But it does not work with smart pointers:

```
std::shared_ptr<C> c2(new C);
example(c2, &C::getId);
```

Error message:

```
error: C2296: '->*' : illegal, left operand has type 'std::shared_ptr<C>'
```

Why? and How to make something that works with both?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851987/pointer-like-classes-and-the-operator

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) doesn't support [pointer-to-member access operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_pointer-to-member_access_operators) (i.e. `->*` and `.*`). So we can't invoke member function pointers with `->*` on it directly. You can change the invoking syntax to use `operator*` and `operator.*`, which works for both raw pointers and smart pointers.

```
template <typename Ptr, typename MemberFunctor>
int example(Ptr ptr, MemberFunctor func )
{
    return ((*ptr).*func)();
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/TIXZ84072)

Answer (score 12):

`std::shared_ptr` doesn't have an `operator->*`. You have two main options:

You could write an overload which takes a `std::shared_ptr` (maybe one for `std::unique_ptr` as well):

```
template <typename T, typename MemberFunctor>
int example(std::shared_ptr<T> ptr, MemberFunctor func )
{
    return ((ptr.get())->*func)();
}
```

However, I would suggest just making `example` take a reference to `T` and calling `func` on it. `example` doesn't need to know anything about how the pointer is stored, so it shouldn't require all of these extra overloads.

```
template <typename T, typename MemberFunctor>
int example(T&& t, MemberFunctor func )
{
    return (std::forward<T>(t).*func)();
}
```

Now if you have a `std::shared_ptr<T>`, you'd call `example` like:

```
example(*my_shared_ptr, my_func);
```

Answer (score 7):

`std::shared_ptr` doesn't overload `operator ->*`. You may add a overload:

```
template <typename Ptr, typename MemberFunctor>
int example(std::shared_ptr<Ptr> ptr, MemberFunctor func )
{
    return (ptr.get()->*func)();
}
```